# Binding the DataSource of a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, repeater

I am using databinding to iterate through a recordset returned from the database, and one of those recordsets is a comma separated list of items - I'm trying to use a second repeater to display each of those items as a hyperlink. So far this is the code that I have:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server" DataSource='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SomeList").ToString().Trim(',') %>'>
<ItemTemplate>
    <a href='http://somesite/downloadattachment.aspx?itemid=<%# Container.ItemIndex %>'><%# Container.DataItem %></a>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The trouble is that so far there are 3 reasons why this doesnt work:

- I get a `server tag is not well formed` error unless I remove the `runat="server"` - why is this? (And why does it work without the `runat="server"`?)
- `Container.DataItem` Evaluates to an instance of `System.Data.DataRowView` - how do I get the current piece of the string that I split?
- More importantly, this only seems to print out 1 `Container.DataItem`, even when I know there is a comma in the string I've given it - any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Eval(), for non-trivial scenarios I generally cast Container.DataItem to the type I want, and then act on it from there in a type-safe way.

The "not well formed" error is caused by the single-quotes around the parameter to Trim(). If you use single quotes on the outside of your attribute definition, you can't use them inside it.  In cases like yours where a databinding definition has a lot of code in it, I often create a helper method (either inside a script runat=server for for MVC views and other inline-code-friendly cases, or in code-behind for traditional web forms apps) which handles the code I want to run.  By refactoring into a method, it clarifies the HTML and sidesteps the lame single/double-quote restrictions.

Regardless of where you put the code, In your case, you want to:

1. cast Container.DataItem to DataRowView
2. extract the SomeList column value using the [] operator
3. call String.Split() on that string to turn your CSV string it into an array of strings
4. use that as a data source of your inner repeater

The code should look something like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server" 
    DataSource='<%# ((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["SomeList"].ToString().Split(new string[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)%>'>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <a href='http://somesite/downloadattachment.aspx?itemid=<%# Container.ItemIndex %>'>
      <%# Container.DataItem %>
    </a>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked a treat & cleared up a lot of how data binding works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you specify the updatecommand, deletecommand to the sqldatasource?

Even if the proper parameters haven't been supplied, the affected rows will always be 0. If it has two parameters for the update command, two parameters have to be supplied through updatecommand.

For more information on this please check this URL: http://www.itpian.com/Coding/4774-Data-binding.aspx